# How to Compile .po file to .mo file , msgfmt not working

Tags: bash, msgfmt

I have to compile a file .po to .mo with msgfmt, so I installed gettext (newest version) and do `chmod 777` to my entire folder.

When I compile the file:

```
msgfmt /home/myuser/file.po -o /home/myuser/file.mo
```

there are no errors, no life signal, nothing.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to change the order of your command:

```
msgfmt /home/myuser/file.po -o /home/myuser/file.mo
```

to:

```
msgfmt -o /home/myuser/file.mo /home/myuser/file.po
```

The usage of msgfmt can you get with:

```
msgfmt --help
```

Comment: you means msgfmt /home/myuser/file.mo -o /home/myuser/file.po ?

Comment: I forgot to write the correct usage. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I remove the menu_text(hint) and put the new en@quot.mo in /boot/grub/local, but boot menu still show the hint text. Anything I'm missing?